# Referencing a cell from another worksheet in excel

Tags: excel, formula

In column A of worksheet i have a list of names. These names also have a corresponding worksheet.

So for example in column A i have a cell with DP in it, there is also a tab called DP.

In column B I am trying to write a formula that looks at column A and then gets the maximum of the the range in in the worksheet.

I have tried this and a few other variations but cant get it to work

=MAX(TEXT(A2,"@")&"!&B2:B5")

So here i am looking at column A, turning it into text putting the exclamation mark which is normal for referencing another worksheeet and then the range. I have tried a few variations of this including not making the B2:B5 a reference rather than text but it seems to refer to the same worksheet rather than the worksheet i want, it therefore gives me a circular reference.

Help Appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=MAX(INDIRECT(A2 & "!B2:B5"))
```

Comment: Hey this works great, let me see what indirect does on the web. Many thanks i was fiddling around with making strings and all sorts

Comment: @MrAssistance - `INDIRECT` function returns the reference specified by a text string.

Comment: @MrAssistance - One more thing, `MAX` function does not accept string as what you were trying to do.

Comment: further to this then say i wanted to drag the formula horizontally so that =MAX(INDIRECT(A2 & "!C2:C5"))....=MAX(INDIRECT(A2 & "!D2:D5"))...how would i account for this since B2 and B5 are fixed?

Comment: @MrAssistance - Gave an answer [at your post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36809836/how-to-drag-horizontally-a-formula-which-is-a-string-fixed). Don't know if this is the best way, but still will give you desired result.

Comment: Yes this would make it different question but the short answer is you would have to use a combination of ADDRESS, ROW() and COLUMN e.g. if you wanted the range to start from the same cell in the other sheet and go down three cells you could use =MAX(INDIRECT($A2 & "!"&ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())&":"&ADDRESS(ROW()+3,COLUMN())))